# How do I populate a textfield with data from a plist

Tags: objective-c, xml, plist, tableview

Im trying to figure out how to populate the textfield in the DVC with data from the plist. I have gotten the data to populate into the tableview cells with know issue. I have not posted the . M for the DVC because simply put. I don't know what to add there ...

xml / plist

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>cellName</key>
        <string>Sharon Lodge No. 327</string>
        <key>cellSubtitle</key>
        <string>McLean, VA</string>
        <key>address</key>
        <string>999 Balls Hill Road</string>
        <key>webSite</key>
        <string>www.website.com</string>
        <key>statedCom</key>
        <string>Hold meetins on...</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>cellName</key>
        <string>Sharon Lodge No. 327</string>
        <key>cellSubtitle</key>
        <string>McLean, VA</string>
        <key>address</key>
        <string>999 Balls Hill Road</string>
        <key>webSite</key>
        <string>www.website.com</string>
        <key>statedCom</key>
        <string>Hold meetins on...</string>
    </dict>
```

.h for DVC

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *address;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *webSite;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *statedCom;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *contactInfo; // added this 

@end
```

.h for talbleview

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface plistTableViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSArray *tabledata;
}

@end
```

.M for Tableview

```
#import "plistTableViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
@interface plistTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation plistTableViewController


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    NSString *mylist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"lodges" ofType:@"plist"];
    tabledata = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:mylist];
    NSLog(@"%@", tabledata);
    [super viewDidLoad];

   }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [tabledata count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if( cell == nil )
    {
        NSLog(@"Cell Creation");
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    //Set Data For each Cell
    cell.textLabel.text = [[tabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"cellName"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[tabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"cellSubtitle"];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}



-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
```

added this 
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self tableView] indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSDictionary *contactInfo = tabledata[indexPath.row];
    DetailViewController *dvc = (DetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
    dvc.contactInfo = contactInfo;
    dvc.address = [[tabledata objectAtIndex:@"address"]]; // this is wrong but not sure about how to write it correctly.

```
}
```

.m to dvc

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize address,webSite,statedCom;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    self.address =[[tabledata objectAtIndex:address]]; // not sure how to complete this



    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making some assumptions about your design - but I think you want to do the following:

Implement a property on the detail view controller for the model    object that you want to represent.  Since you are using the built-in collection classes `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` straight from the    property list, I suspect the property on the detail view controller  will be something like: `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary

*contactInfo;`

Set this property on the detail view controller in the    `prepareForSegue:sender:` method.  You'll need the get the    appropriate dictionary from the selected index path as follows:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self tableView] indexPathForSelectedRow];
NSDictionary *contactInfo = tabledata[indexPath.row];
DetailViewController *dvc = (DetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
dvc.contactInfo = contactInfo;
```

Then in the `DetailViewController` `viewDidLoad` method, you can set the UI elements to whatever entries in the `NSDictionary` `self.contactInfo` you need.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! I'd give you +10 if I could :)